# React JS - How can we change url with link instead of id in react router dom

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

How can we change URL by link(which is present in the database) instead of id...

it will use by usequery hook

Sectioninner by Id =>

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const fetchPost = ({ queryKey }) => {
    const postId = queryKey[1];
  return axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/posts/${postId}`);
}

export const SectioninnerById = (postId) => {
    return useQuery (['Post', postId], fetchPost);
    
};
```

{Database which having present link}

```
{
"code": 200,
"message": "post Added Sucessfully",
"addPosts": {
    "link": "The-Boys-Season-01-02-(2019-2020)-Dual-Audio-{Hindi-English}-1080p-x264-||-1080p 10bit-||-Bluray ",
    "title": "The Boys Season 01-02 (2019-2020) Dual Audio {Hindi-English} 1080p x264 || 1080p 10bit || Bluray ",
    "image": "image_1649565125439.png",
    "HeadingTitle": "Download The Boys Season 01-02 (2019-2020) Dual Audio {Hindi-English} 1080p x264 || 1080p 10bit || Bluray ",
    "datetime": "08 April 2022",
    "smallTitle": "Download The Boys Season 01-02 (2019-2020) Dual Audio {Hindi-English} 1080p x264 || 1080p 10bit || Bluray || WEB-",
    "MoviesContent": "Parents need to know that The Boys is a dark comedy series about a world in which superheroes aren't actually the good guys. This means that the \"heroes\" in the show are constantly doing terrible things including, but not limited to, sexual assault and acts of terrorism. As a result, the show contains just about every type of adult content you can imagine -- simulated sex, male and female nudity,",
    "allCategories": "1080P,2160P,WEB-DL",
    "_id": "62525dc5b5254b12e0e08419",
    "__v": 0
},
"image": "http://localhost:5000/image_1649565125439.png"
```

}

Sectioninner.js {which is the sectioninner fetch by id of the post with mapping}

```js
import React from 'react'

function Sectioninner() {
const { postId } = useParams();
const {isLoading, data, isError, error}= SectioninnerById(postId)

if(isLoading){
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>
}

if(isError){
    return <h2>{error.message}</h2>
}


    return (
        <>
            <div className="downloadcontainer">
                <div className="container12">
                    {/* Path */}
                    <p>Home » {data?.data.HeadingTitle}</p>
                    {/* Categories */}
                    <p> {data?.data.Categories}</p>
                </div>
           </div>
```

App.js {main component only return statement}

```js
return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <Router>
        <>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/:postId' element={<Sectioninner />} />
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Section />} ></Route>
        <Route path= '*' element={<Missing />} />
      </Routes>
      </>
    </Router>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the question. What is the problem? You can't crate a link? Or toy want to create a dynamic route or something?

Comment: I want create a dynamic link which is present in database is based on the title of the post (here I am using the post id to rendering single post in single page like ecommerce website) and if I am using the title then it simply to understand the users what are they view... (Not with ID of the post)

Comment: Can you show this function? `SectioninnerById(postId)`